# Calling random audio files with PiFm + Node.js

Tags: pi-3, node.js, pifm

I am trying to play a random amount of random audio files over PIFM using node.js

```
// A function that will let me call and play one random audio file. 

function audio1(){

var child_process = require("child_process") //calls child process 

//These are my 9 audio wavs that will play one after the other on pi2fm
var ran1 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio1.wav 103.50"); 
var ran2 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio2.wav 103.50");
var ran3 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio3.wav 103.50");
var ran4 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio4.wav 103.50");
var ran5 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio5.wav 103.50");
var ran6 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio6.wav 103.50");
var ran7 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio7.wav 103.50");
var ran8 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio8.wav 103.50");
var ran9 = child_process.execSync("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio9.wav 103.50");

function randomFrom(array) {return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];} // this creates a function (randomFrom()) that selects a random variable in array 

var ranAudio = [ran1, ran2, ran3, ran4, ran5, ran6, ran7, ran8 ,ran9]; //this is my array of variable containg execution of audio on Pi2fm


randomFrom(ranAudio).call(); // feeds ranAudio to randomFrom() 

}

//calls audio1();
audio1();
```

with the above code the files are playing one after another (I don't want this). And then when it gets to randomFrom() where I would expect one of the files to play randomly I am getting the following error:

```
randomFrom(ranAudio).call();
                     ^

TypeError: randomFrom(...).call is not a function
```

To clarify, I just want a random amount of audio files (1- 9) to play, however, so far I can not get even one random file to play.

Any suggestions, appreciated etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
// A function that will let me call and play one random audio file. 


function audio1(){


var child_process = require("child_process") //calls child process 

//variables ran1 - ran7 are each a path to Pi2fm + audiofile + frequency
var ran1 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio1.wav 103.50"); 
var ran2 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio2.wav 103.50");
var ran3 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio3.wav 103.50");
var ran4 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio4.wav 103.50");
var ran5 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio5.wav 103.50");
var ran6 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio6.wav 103.50");
var ran7 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio7.wav 103.50");
var ran8 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio8.wav 103.50");
var ran9 = ("sudo -E /Path/to/pi2fm audio9.wav 103.50");


// puts all audio files into an array
var randomAudio  = [ran1, ran2, ran3, ran4, ran5, ran6, ran7];

//creates a variable ranNUM  with a random integer
var ranNum  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
console.log(ranNum);//prints that number just so I can test

var x = 1; //for use in loop

while(x <=  ranNum){ //while x is less than the random Number.

var audioRan = randomAudio[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomAudio.length)];//select a random audio file
var play = child_process.execSync(audioRan);//play that random audio file using child_process.exexSync
x++; //incremenet x by 1 each loop

}

}

audio1();//call function
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.